# ArcGIS client/server overhead

Tags: architecture, client, arcgis, arcgis-server

How the ArcGIS server handle the client/server overhead?
what are the techiniques it uses to handle the high overhead?
Are they stable solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest clarifying your question a bit more.  There isn't an overwhelmingly high overhead to ArcGIS server, unless you consider the individual instances of SOC and SOM processes that are started.

Also, what versions are you referring to?  I know the architecture changed a lot from 10 to 10.1.

I would note, however, that ESRI's technology is rarely completely stable - although that is a subjective view.